# Jquery Complicated mouse hover Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

Can some one please tell me  how I can implement this effect easily using jquery/javascript? http://goo.gl/xaC5C "Digital Creativity is our Happy Place" I need the effect to be responsive(increase/decrease size based on browser width) Is there any script in the market which I can buy or download for this?

Thanks for your help in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

The animation that you're looking at is all achieved through canvas manipulation. [Link to canvas API.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)